# Before plugin for Submit query method

Tags: magento-2.1.7, plugin, before-plugin

I am trying to create before plugin for SubmitQuote method of `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement` but plugin is not hitting.

Its a api req so i have declared the plugin in `/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml`.

The declaration is as follows:

```
public function beforeSubmitQuote(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $subject, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, $orderData = []){
//***Code Here****
}
```

Please help me to find the reason why its not hitting.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't allow pluginize for protected method. [See more detail here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

In that case you can use following event:

```
sales_model_service_quote_submit_before
```

Comment: Check limitation section. “No-public method “ not allowed